# Correct implementation of multi-tenancy in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

Lets say I set up and create a new Azure Account and Subscription. Azure automatically creates me an Azure AD called "*somedomain.onmicrosoft.com*".

Later I deploy REST API and Angular SPA app to Azure. Since I'm using Azure AD for authentication and authorization on both of the applications I register them on my Azure AD, under the domain "*somedomain.onmicrosoft.com*".

Everything works fine, however after some time I realize that I want to allow access to my services/apps to other organizations. After doing some research I realize that what I want to achieve is *multi-tenancy*.

In order to register a new *tenant* I do the following:

1. Go to Azure portal.
2. On the left blade menu click on "Create a resource" and search for "Azure Active Directory".
3. Create a new directory called "*tenant-1.onmicrosoft.com*".

Next, I update my registered apps (on "*somedomain.onmicrosoft.com*") according to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant) - enabling multi tenancy and common endpoint.

After all of this, both users from AD "*somedomain.onmicrosoft.com*" and "*tenant-1.onmicrosoft.com*" should be able to authenticate and access my services.

**Question**

Is this the correct way of achieving and implementing multi tenancy?

Comment: From Azure AD point of view, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create a new Azure AD tenant (xyz.onmicrosoft.com). Just register the application in the existing tenant or mark the existing application as multi-tenant. Then, existing other AAD tenants will be able to signup to use your app without doing further registrations. You will need to modify your app code to accept tokens from other tenants, e.g. [enter link description here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect) This link points to a regular .NET web app, not SPA. You will need to translate it to your SPA environment.

Comment: From what I understand you must have a "root" ADD, then you can register "child" AAD under root AAD. In my case this so called root AAD would be the one that I automatically get when I create my Azure account.

Comment: Never heard of 'root' or 'child' AADs. A multi-tenant app is registered (using App Registration) - it gets an Application and a Service principal object - in one AAD tenant and can be subscribed to (just a Service principal object) in any other AAD tenant. For example, you could look at O365 as a multi-tenant app registered in the Microsoft Corporate tenant and subscribed to thousands of other customer tenants. When you subscribe, you effectively tell your tenant that it is OK to respond to token requests from that application. You typically subscribe when you first sign in to the app.

Comment: That O365 example is very good, clears up a lot of stuff! Thank you a lot and excuse my awful comparison with root and child.

Comment: By the way, can you somehow restrict what tenants can use your app?

Comment: Yes, use the issuer id claim to decide whether you will accept a token from this tenant or not.

Comment: I'm using Angular as my front end. I was wondering if you could somehow create a list of allowed tenants on Azure portal itself but as far as I can see it's no possible. I guess I could use something like Identity Server.

Comment: Rather keep a list of allowed issuers in your back-end API and when you validate tokens received by it from your JS fron-end, validate whether token issuer is in the list.

Comment: You're in luck, I just wrote an article on that: https://joonasw.net/view/best-practices-for-n-tenant-azure-ad-applications

Comment: Good blog as usual @juunas .. @OverflowStack you haven't mentioned explicitly whether you're using Azure AD v1 or v2 endpoint.. Do note that sample link mentioned in answer is for v1, while the blog from juunas uses issuer urls as per v2. Basic concept will stay the same but there will be small differences.. like issuer urls for v1 are of the format `https://sts.windows.net/<TenantId>` while for v2 endpoint issuer urls are like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/v2.0`

Comment: Yeah, I figured I'd have to use v1. While the example @juunas gave works perfectly it made me wonder about the following scenario - what if we have two types of tenants: tenants that can access all functionality and tenants that can access very limited functionality. I think in this case given example no longer works.

Comment: Well, all those tenants are still allowed to login, but you'd have to do authorization after that to limit what they can do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your high level use case but one thing to note about the AAD multi-tenant approach. You are assuming that person signing in has an Azure AD tenant, for example through Office365.

If they don't have an Azure AD then they won't be able to sign in.

You 'could' create an AAD for each new tenant and create a user account in there. 
They would have the bob@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com address and could add their own domain later.

That way they can then take advantage of all the enterprise features of AzureAD.
It might be a use case, but I think you would need an AAD per tenant and I'm not sure of the limits or if this is best practice.

You can also look at B2C if you want social logins/other OpenIDConnect.